# How to develop Firefox Add-on SDK extension using localforage

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk, localforage

I am trying to develop a Firefox Add-on SDK extension that saves data using the localforage library, but I am getting the following error:

```
Full message: ReferenceError: self is not defined
Full stack: polyfill@resource://browser-journey/node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js:259:9
@resource://browser-journey/node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js:689:1
@resource://browser-journey/node_modules/localforage/dist/localforage.js:7:2
@resource://browser-journey/index.js:6:19
run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:147:19
```

I installed localforage using npm.

I think the problem might be because of [this issue](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage/issues/469) in localforage. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authors of localforage don't intend to support Firefox Addons, but it doesn't mean it is impossible. 
Here is the related issue: https://github.com/mozilla/localForage/issues/584

You could write a custom driver for localforage: https://github.com/mozilla/localForage/pull/282

Or add this code at the top of the `dist/localforage.min.js` file before including it in your addon:

```
/**
 * Detect Firefox SDK Addon environment and prepare some globals
 *
 * @author Dumitru Uzun (DUzun.Me)
 */
(function (window, undefined) {
    if (typeof exports != "object" || typeof module == "undefined") return;

    if ( window && window.Array === Array ) try {
        window.window = window;

        // Timers
        if ( typeof setTimeout == 'undefined' ) {
            expo(
                require("sdk/timers")
              , [
                    'setTimeout'  , 'clearTimeout',
                    'setImmediate', 'clearImmediate'
                ]
            );
        }

        // Blob, FileReader
        var Cu = require("chrome").Cu;
        var Services = Cu['import']("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});
        expo(
            Services
          , ['Blob', 'FileReader']
        );
        expo(
            Services.appShell && Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow
          , ['Blob', 'FileReader']
        );

        // IndexedDB
        expo(require('sdk/indexed-db'));

    } catch(err) {
        console.log('error', err);
    }

    function expo(ctx, props) {
        if ( !ctx ) return;
        if ( !props ) props = Object.keys(ctx);
        for(var i=props.length,p; i--;) {
            p = props[i];
            if ( ctx[p] != undefined && !(p in window) ) {
              window[p] = ctx[p];
            }
        }
        return ctx;
    }
}(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage/pull/470) pull request was just merged to the library and seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: This didn't solved the problem of using `localforage` inside an Addon.
`localforage` checks for available storage engines by checking global variables like `typeof indexedDB !== 'undefined'`, but `indexedDB` is not available in the addon's environment. It has to be required explicitly bu `var { indexedDB } = require('sdk/indexed-db');`.